# Using cache brokes redirecting

Tags: redirect, htaccess, cache

In my .htaccess I have a rewrite rule to redirect from `/index.php` to `/`, and it works perfectly immediately after I clear cache, but doesn't work after some time (maybe page `/index.php` got cached). I'm using cache engine from plugin PageSpeed Ninja, which doesn't have options to exclude specific pages from being cached. Can I programmatically make redirect to work?

Comment: Please include the contents of your .htaccess file.

Comment: Redirects of the form `index.php` to `/` are only to catch edge cases (outdated search engine indexes etc.), they should not be part of the normal navigation of your site, so the response is unlikely to be cached in these cases anyway? But there would seem to be something a bit odd going on here... The only reason the redirect would not work is if the `index.php` had been cached by the _browser_ (if your redirect is in `.htaccess`) and the redirect itself is _not_ cached. The redirect should be a 301 (permanent) - so the redirect itself should also be cached. (?)